Detecting/removing thin sections of polygons
Given a non-self-intersecting polygon made of straight segments how do you detect/trim sections of the polygon that are "thin"?

If an algorithm exists for this, then great! If not, then...

I think the "correct" definition of "thickness" at a point on the edge is related to the smallest circle that touches that edge and some other part of the polygon.
The thickness at the point where two lines meet is always zero so there will need to be some minimum allowed angle.

As for the algorithm.. some sort of checking every line against every other line? Some sort of convert to convex hulls first? Some sort of triangulation of the polygon?

This was answered in this question using the python library "shapely". A general explanation is you shrink (sometimes called buffer) the polygon by some amount, grow/buffer the polygon by some % more than you shrunk it, then take the intersection of this new polygon and your original polygon.
The amount you shrink approximately defines how narrow a "hallway" can be before its removed. The % more you grow the polygon (called "cofactor" in the linked answer) approximately defines the angle of "spikes" that are allowed in the polygon (a bigger number means allowing sharper spikes).


I added an answer to the question you linked to that follows the same general idea but gives a resulting polygon that will be closer in shape compared to the input polygon than the original answer.

Some minor corrections to your explanation for clarity if others user read/use it: 1) you can do an intersection with the original polygon, not a union, 2) the amount you shrink is ~half of the minimum width you want to retain.

(@Pieter unless you suggest Christopher Pratt should edit the post accordingly, I prefer that you yourself edit in corrections to what you clearly identify as simple mistakes.)

It was indeed a suggestion @christopher pratt to update his post

My error, good catch. I updated the post.
